# how to get the value of an array and get the total numbers of the same value in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',',$cart);

            //what should i do next?? the value of $items is 4,4,2,2,2,4
```

Comment: You should start by storing an *array* in the session instead of a string. Makes things simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get array without duplicate use array_unique()

```
                $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
                    if ($cart) {
                        $items = explode(',',$cart);
                $unique_items=array_unique($items);  // gives 4,2


    $result_array=array();

        foreach($unique_items as $uni_item)
        {
          $item_occurence_count=0;
           $totalvalue=0;

         foreach($items as $item)
            {
            $item_value=$item;
            $totalvalue+=$item_value;
             if($item==$uni_item)
               {
                  ++$item_occurence_count;
                  $result_array[$uni_item]=$item_occurence_count;
               }
            }
        }
print_r($result_array);  // gives Array ( [4] => 3 [2] => 3 )
```

Hope this is what required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re looking for [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) that counts the values in an array.

Comment: it will give me the total numbers of the same values? like value 4 is equal to 3 and 2 is equal to 3? tnx. maybe got to read that array_count_values.